# Rewrite Incoming url in Node.js App

Tags: node.js

I need my incoming url to be rewrite such as 
Incoming url is

```
http://localhost:8080/test/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

I need to write a proxy such as all urls starting with /test/bower_components should be rewritten such as to remove /test from the url.
expected output is to be

```
http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

Am trying to use this module [connect modrewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-modrewrite)

```
 app.use(modRewrite([

    '^/email/api/(.*)$ [L]' 

  ]));
```

Comment: If you use Express you can use the [`static`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) function.

Comment: @Marty Its not about just static files its about all incoming request.

Comment: Yeah so the static thing you could use to achieve what you want like `app.use('/bower_components', express.static('/test/bower_components'))`.

Comment: @Marty What about incoming api request